# event object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When Ever i submit this form the event.target turn out to be null this should hold the value of the text field?
why is this happening as it is supposed the have values of the text field

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.fun = props;
  }

  handleOnsubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Inside ");
    console.log(event.target);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnsubmit}>
          UserName:
          <input type="text"></input>
          <br></br>

          Password:
          <input type="text"></input>
          <br></br>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: `this should hold the value of the text field` - no, it should be the `form`, as that is the element emitting the submit event - I don't know what *react* does to events to make it `null`, but it definitely would never be a text field

Comment: @bhoomeendra check improved your code https://stackoverflow.com/a/59450677/6544460

Comment: event.target.values is supposed to have the value the event.target does contain the form when when console log it

Answer (score 1):

`event.target` is array of form controls. So to access value of first input (UserName in your case), use `event.target[0].value`

This how `OnSubmit` will look like

```
  handleOnsubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Inside ");
    console.log(`UserName: ${event.target[0].value}`);
    console.log(`Password: ${event.target[1].value}`);
  }
```

And [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formsubmit-tqpsq)

Answer (score 0):

It's works. Your check is wrong...

check this demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bhaskara-qr44t

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `event` object inside the `handleOnsubmit` method is referring to the on submit event which occurred on your form. So its target will be the form itself (not `null`).

Instead of getting the value of the input when the form is submitted, you can instead keep two state properties which keep track of the state of the text inputs in your form. Then, whenever your inputs change (using the `onChange`) event, you can update their respective states. This means that when you submit your form, you can reference this state using `this.state`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: "", password: "" };
  }

  handleOnsubmit = e => { // e.target here is the form
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.username, this.state.password);
  };

  handleInput = e => { // e.target here is the input element
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnsubmit}>
          UserName:
          <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.handleInput} />
          <br />
          Password:
          <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleInput} />
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

See working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formsubmit-ygktz)

Also note, the `input` tag is self-closing.